# How to read file names from GCP buckets recursively using a composer DAG

Tags: google-cloud-platform, composer-php, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to read the file names from GCS bucket recursively from all folders, subfolders under the bucket using a composer DAG. Is it possible? For example i have bucket with corresponding folders and sub folders  as mentioned below. static is the bucket name.

static/folder1/subfolder1/file1.json
static/folder1/subfolder2/file2.json
static/folder1/subfolder3/file3.json
static/folder1/subfolder3/file4.json

I want to read the files recursively and put the data in two variables like below.

bucketname = static
filepath = static/folder1/subfolder3/file4.json

Comment: Which operator are you using? Or it's the topic of the question: what is the right operator for reading in Storage with composer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Airflow's `BashOperator` to use the GCS CLI tool ([docs here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/ls#directory-by-directory-flat-and-recursive-listings)).

An example could be the following:

```py
read_files = BashOperator(
    task_id='read_files',
    bash_command='gsutil ls -r gs://bucket',
    dag=dag,
)
```

Edit: Since you want to capture the output and the `BashOperator` only pushes the last line of stdout to XCom, I would suggest using a `PythonOperator` which calls a custom Python callable which uses either the GCS API or even the CLI tool via `subprocess` to collect all file names and push it to XCom for subsequent use by downstream tasks. Unless you do not need other tasks to use this data at all, in which case you can process it however you like (not clear from the question).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Used python operator with GCS API to do this.

Comment: @ShilabaRoul Cool, glad I could help :)